# Extending jQuery with CoffeeScript class

Tags: jquery, coffeescript

I'm new to CoffeeScript, and I like the CoffeeScript classes, but can't work out how to extend them in jQuery using jQuery.prototype.

This is for part of my app that holds sort-of global state variables, so I want to call it via **$.myThing.myFunction()**, and not the usual $.fn.extend / $().myThing() extending way.

I can get it to work like this:

```
$ = jQuery
$.myThing = $.myThing || {}

$.extend $.myThing, {
  myProperty: 0
  myFunction: ->
}
```

Which is okay, but then I can't use it as a class, and the structure doesn't look pretty my pycharm.  (Which, being honest is probably bothering more than the whole class thing...)

What I want, is to do something like this:

```
$ = jQuery
$.myThing = $.myThing || {}

class myThing
  myProperty: 0
  myFunction: ->

$.extend $.myThing, myThing()
```

But it doesn't work (other than looking pretty in pycharm).  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
class jQuery.myThing
  myProperty: 0
  myFunction: ->
```

Compiles to:

```
jQuery.myThing = (function() {

  function myThing() {}

  myThing.prototype.myProperty = 0;

  myThing.prototype.myFunction = function() {};

  return myThing;

})();
```

**Edit:** `$.myThing` as an instance of the class:

```
class myThing
  myProperty: 0
  myFunction: ->

jQuery.myThing = new myThing
```

Comment: Closer - I hadn't looked at how the classes were compiling.  In this case, $.myThing returns the prototype, instead of a single instance of the object, so I'm guessing I need to add "new" in there somewhere.

Comment: I didn't realize you wanted `$.myThing` to be an instance of the class. See edit above.

Comment: I don't think I ever quite understood prototypes... thanks. That works perfectly, and even looks nice in pycharm.  Seems I can also do "$.extend $.myThing, new myThing()".

Answer (score 0):

I wanted my jquery method to act like a regular jQuery extension -- be a jQuery object, with all the jQuery methods such as each, html, and so on -- but also to have the properties of my class.  Here's my solution:

```
Object.prototype.extend = (klass)->
  for key, value of klass::
    @[key] = value

class MyClass
  myclassmethod: ->

$.fn.myjqextension = ()->
  @extend MyClass
  @myclassmethod()
```

See: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/452

http://jimmycuadra.com/posts/coffeescript-classes-under-the-hood